# When used with a paginated query, how many joined records do includes load into memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

One particular page in a Rails app keeps raising `Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)` errors on Heroku.

This page has several remote [datatables](https://datatables.net). These datatables are populated by ajax queries that look something like this.

```
User.
  find( params[:id] ).
  events.
  includes(:city,:state,:country).
  where("users.name ilike :search or cities.name ilike :search or states.name ilike :search or countries.name ilike :search", search: "%#{params[:search][:value]}%" ).
  page(page).per(10)
```

The tables are large, but as the query is paginated, I did not expect much loaded into memory. It was suggested to me that while paginate may limit how many `Events` are loaded into memory, the `includes` line will load all the `city`, `state` and `county` records.

1. Does this sound correct? Will the above query load all joined tables
   referenced through the `includes` call?
2. How should this query be changed to ensure memory is used efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Not all, but those associated to user model with foreign key.
String search at db level with iLike itself is heavy, but if you really want to do ilike search, one scope of optimisation i see is selecting only name column from all the tables. If you notice in the logs, your query would be `select * from` type.

Comment: thanks, this is a useful suggestion. I have been experimenting with this a little, and have a couple of questions. Is there an alternative to ilike that would allow case-insensitive, partial string matches to be performed more efficiently? I see what you mean about using `select`, but while this limits the number of columns, it still appears to still load all joined rows (e.g., 10,000 database rows) into memory, rather than only the 10 paginated rows I need. Is there a better way to have ActiveRecord query on joined attributes, but only load the required records into memory for displaying?

Comment: I agree @AndyHarvey , but can't think of an alternative to iLike. However, looking at your code, I think your model has_one of each city, state and country. How about saving those attributes in the model and let's name it place. Run a before_save/before_create callback doing: `Model.place = "#{city.name}, #{state.name}, #{country.name}"`. Now you don't need to preload them and query reduces to `where("users.name ilike :search or MODEL.place ilike :search", search: "%#{params[:search][:value]}%" )`. What do you think?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will think about this some more. the actual implementation is a little more complicated, as there are several datatables referencing several different base models, all with search queries on associations. so this solution would require adding and updating a lot of extra database columns only for the purpose of search. it may be this is the best way to go, but i'll need to think through the pros and cons. anyway, thanks for the suggestion. this has given me a much better/clearer starting point.

Comment: Ok, would appreciate if you share your final implementation/solution here as I have been using solr for search and it makes me curious to know how better it can be implemented in relational db queries.